# WPF tooltips from database

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip

I need to be able to edit tooltips at runtime in an 3-tier WPF app. (This would probably be allowed for an admin, not for every user.) What I would like is to have the tooltips in the database, and I've been looking at various techniques to achieve this. Josh Smith has a nice example of using a tooltip converter ([here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/dynamically-generating-tooltip-text/)). However, I need to link a tooltips to individual UI controls, so each control would have to have a unique identifier. Unfortunately that's not required by WPF. I wouldn't want to give each control a name. I have a recollection that you can somehow generate x:Uid's but can't remember how. Also, I'd like to somehow hook to the tooltip mechanism instead of defining a converter to each control. I realize I maybe aiming a little high, but any ideas, anyone?

Comment: So you mean that ANY UI element in the visual tree may have a tooltip defined? defined by the end user? Please post a screenshot or a picture to depict what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)).

In this solution if you want to set ToolTip from db you must set name of the element.

First you must create class that will hold your data from db:

```
class ToolTipContainer
{
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }       
}
```

Next you should use `VisualTreeHelper` to iterate through all elements:

```
class ToolTipManager
{
    List<ToolTipContainer> source;

    public ToolTipManager(List<ToolTipContainer> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {                
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);                                 
            ((dynamic)childVisual).ToolTip = source.Where(x => x.ElementName == childVisual.GetValue(Control.NameProperty) as string).Select(x => x.ToolTip).FirstOrDefault();                                
            EnumVisual(childVisual);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFToolTipDB.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="Button" Content="Click me" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="150" />
            <Button Name="Button1" Content="Click me!" />
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" Text="My text block" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Name="tbName" Text="Name:" />
                <TextBox Name="tbEnterName" MinWidth="150" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // When you don't specify name of the element you can set default ToolTip.
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = string.Empty, ToolTip = "Empty ToolTip!!!" });
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = "Button", ToolTip = "Click me" });
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = "Button1", ToolTip = "Click me!" });
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = "TextBlock", ToolTip = "My TextBlock" });
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = "tbName", ToolTip = "Enter your name!" });
        source.Add(new ToolTipContainer { ElementName = "tbEnterName", ToolTip = "Please enter your name here!" });            

        var ttManager = new ToolTipManager(source);
        ttManager.EnumVisual(this.Content as Visual);
    }
    List<ToolTipContainer> source = new List<ToolTipContainer>();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Any reason why you chose to use a List, or this just for demo purposes? I was thinking of loading the tooltips to a `Dictionary` on startup.

Comment: @Rubio I choose `List<T>` only for demo purpose, you can use Dictionary. But if you use my solution you can in simple way extend tooltips, maybe image, who wrote this tooltip, when the tooltip was changed, etc.